# System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive and CRC32

Tags: .net-4.5, crc32

What CRC32 code is System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive using underneath the covers since .NET does not have CRC32?

Comment: What, specifically, are you interested in, the actual source code? `ZipArchive` uses CRC32, as required by the ZIP format. It'd be cool if the BCL exposed that implementation for use by user code, but it's a pretty simple thing to implement.

Comment: Are you looking for a CRC32 implementation? ZipArchive There are a lot of custom CRC32 implementations, e.g. http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/Calculating_CRC32_in_C_and_NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.IO.Compression` assembly contains an `internal` class `Crc32Helper` that's used to calculate the checksum.